# How exactly works this Hibernate entity class? How to correctly define a field representd by another entity class?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am pretty new in **Hibernate** and I have the following doubt.

I have this entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "KM_COUNTRY_AREA")
public class KMCountryArea implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long idCountryArea;

    @Column(name = "nomeFolder")
    private String nomeFolder;

    @Column(name = "country")
    private KMCountry country;

    // GETTER & SETTER METHODS

}
```

I have a doubt related to this field definition:

```
@Column(name = "country")
private KMCountry country;
```

where **KMCountry** is another entity class. So what it exactly means? I think that Hibernate automatically use the id of the table mappend by the **KMCountry** class.

Is it correct or am I missing something?

**EDIT-1:**

So I have changed from:

```
@Column(name = "country")
private KMCountry country;
```

to:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "country", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private KMCountry country;
```

where **country** is the name of the field that will contain the KMCountry id into the KM_COUNTRY_AREA table on my DB. Is it correct?

or maybe the correct syntax is:

```
@OneToOne
private KMCountry country;
```

because I have to use the primary key of the **KMCountry country** object?

What is the meaning of the **cascade = CascadeType.ALL** attribute?

Tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't define it using the *@Column* annotation, you have to use [**Mapping entity associations/relationships**](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association).

And depending on your case I think you can use the **One-to-one mapping**.

Take a look at this tutorial:

- [**Hibernate One to One Mapping (Annotation) Example**](http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/09/hibernate-one-to-one-mapping.html).

## Edit:

To answer the questions in your EDIT:

1. ***The field definition:***

Use the following code to define your field:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "countryArea", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private KMCountry country;
```

Where **countryArea** refers to the field you have to add in your KMcountry class like the following:

```
@OneToOne  
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn  
private KMCountryArea countryArea;
```

And in your DB you will only have a reference to the `KMCountryArea` **id** in your `KM_Country` table.

2. ***The meaning of `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`:***

> Cascading is about keeping dependency between two entities, for
> example deletion of one object from the database causing deletion of
> other dependent objects and **CascadeType.ALL** means that all the changes at parent class object will effect child class object too

### JPA Cascade Types :

The cascade types supported by the Java Persistence Architecture are as below:

- **CascadeType.PERSIST :** means that save() or persist() operations cascade to related entities.
- **CascadeType.MERGE :** means that related entities are merged into managed state when the owning entity is merged.
- **CascadeType.REFRESH :** does the same thing for the refresh() operation.
- **CascadeType.REMOVE :** removes all related entities association with this setting when the owning entity is deleted.
- **CascadeType.DETACH :** detaches all related entities if a “manual detach” occurs.
- **CascadeType.ALL :** is shorthand for all of the above cascade operations.

Take a look at [**Hibernate Annotations-Cascade**](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-cascade) and [**Hibernate JPA Cascade Types**](http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/09/25/hibernate-jpa-cascade-types/) for further information.

Comment: Tnx, I have added an edit update to my original post. Please, can you see it and say me if now it is correct?